# How can I download pictures to an IPad 2

Tags: ipad

I have tried Ubuntu to IPad moving pictures with the two directly connected without being able to see pictures on the ipad. I tried the cloud in the hope that I could copy the pictures to the cloud. This part is successful. I've got them in a pictures directory.

For the ipad, I've installed the ubuntu 1 ap and it is recognized but am unsure of how to get the sync to happen so I can see the pictures on the ipad's photo application.

Comment: To determine the correct response, please edit your question to include the Ubuntu version you are using-

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an ipad, but on android, you have to manually find the file(s) and download them. Also, you may want to check if your picture file is being synced to ubuntu one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Emmett. Before trying the cloud I hooked the ipad up to my ubuntu pc after taking several photos on the ipad. I was able to find the directory the photos were in but when I copied my pictures over to that folder the ipad wouldn't display the new pictures. The pictures are all jpegs so I am surprised that the copy didn't work. Are there any steps I'm overlooking? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, when you plug an apple device into any computer, it shows up as a removable drive with the pictures in a sub-folder. This makes it easy to get pictures off. But the only way to get them on is via itunes, or an app.